# Delaying jQuery toggleClass effect until a slide animation has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm having some issues with the jQuery delay() function.
I'm currently using it to try and force a toggleClass action to wait until the slideUp animation has completed on one of my divs however it doesn't appear to be working.

My style aims at having a bar with rounded corners that when clicked expands to reveal further content with the round corners of the bar at bottom becoming squared so as to look as though the bar has actually expanded to reveal the content. This is fine and it works however, when I collapse the expansion, the bar needs to go back to having rounded corners at the bottom after the collapse animation has completed. At the moment it seems to fire before this animation has completed.

I read somewhere online that the jQuery 'slow' speed of transition is 600 milliseconds to I set the delay to 800 to make sure it is out of the way but again this hasn't actually done anything.

Any suggestions? Code and fiddle below:

```
$(function() {
        $('span.history_record_toggle').click(function () {
            if($(this).hasClass('collapsed')){
                $(this).text('Show +');
                $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
                $(this)
                    .closest('.history_record_container')
                    .find('.history_record_body')
                    .slideUp('slow',function() {
                });
                $(this)
                    .parent()
                    .toggleClass('squared_bottom');
            }else{
                $(this).text('Hide -');
                $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
                $(this)
                    .closest('.history_record_container')
                    .find('.history_record_body')
                    .slideDown('slow',function() {
                });
                $(this)
                    .parent()
                    .delay(800)
                    .toggleClass('squared_bottom');
            };                                      
        });
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/KFeHd/6/

Comment: Why the downvote? There is nothing whatsoever wrong with my question.

Comment: I didn't understand it either. Up voted to take out the coward negative given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery animations and effects have callback functions for what you want to happen after it finishes.

E.g.

```
var thisParent = $(this).parent();
$(this).closest('.history_record_container').find('.history_record_body').slideDown('slow',function() {
  $(thisParent).toggleClass('squared_bottom');
});
```

Comment: If you look at my code though this will not work as the element that is clicked has a different parent to that which the animation is called on. Therefore the wrong element would be targeted with the style. I've tried this method and it does not work.

Comment: @jezzipin Yes it will work, you'd just need to make the parent a variable outside the function. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KFeHd/9/)

```
    $(function() {
        $('span.history_record_toggle').click(function () {
            $zis = $(this);
            if($zis.hasClass('collapsed')){
                $zis.text('Show +')
                .removeClass('collapsed')
                .closest('.history_record_container')
                .find('.history_record_body')
                .slideUp('slow',function() {
                    $zis.parent().removeClass('squared_bottom');
                });
                $zis.parent().addClass('squared_bottom');
            }else{
                $zis.text('Hide -')
                .addClass('collapsed')
                .closest('.history_record_container')
                .find('.history_record_body')
                .slideDown('slow',function() {
                });
                $zis.parent().addClass('squared_bottom');
            };                                      
        });
    });
```